# DB2 - How to retrieve the last substring starting from the end

Tags: sql, database, select, db2, substring

i'm trying to retrieve the last substring from a string, starting from the end.
Here it is my dataset:

Input:

- BRAND_Arnette
- BRAND_Persol
- MODEL_CODE_DISPLAY_226781

Output:

- Arnette
- Persol
- 226781

What i 've managed to do is to retrieve what i need, but i'm not using an universal approach, because i'm considerging always the latest 10 chars, starting from the right:

```
SELECT
SUBSTR(RIGHT(rtrim(cast(attrval.IDENTIFIER as char(50))), 10), LOCATE('_',RIGHT(rtrim(cast(attrval.IDENTIFIER as char(50))), 10))+1)
                    FROM ...
```

How can this select be edited so it can be always valid? Thanks

Comment: Always mention your Db2-server platform (z/os, i series,  linux/unix/windows) and Db2-server version when asking for help. Because the answer can depend on these facts, and there are special tags per platform.  In this case, if your Db2-server has function REGEXP_EXTRACT then you could use that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following expression:

```
SUBSTR (identifier, LOCATE_IN_STRING (identifier, '_', -1) + 1)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8a76b54ef93304d7b305bebcb9046287) example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(identifier, '[^_]+$')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=096aa796a73e1d25a7c87266e087308b) is a db<>fiddle.